# Redirect after POST django rest framework

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am submitting a POST request via django form to my Django Rest Framework api.

Here is a snippet of my form:

```
<form action="{% url 'entry-list' %}" method="POST" class="form" role="form">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}
<div class = "form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default btn-block">Save</button>
</div>
```

**`views.py`**:

```
class entry_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class= EntrySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.partial = True
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

I am making a successful POST (and item is created in database), however once I save I go to the url `/api/entry/` which shows my api w/Markdown. I'd like to have it go back to a specific url.

Is there a way to customize where the `POST` redirect to if successful?

Added Serializer:

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntrySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        for x in self.fields:
            self.fields[x].required = False
```

Comment: Can you share your  `EntrySerializer`?

Comment: editted to add serializer

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`viewsets.ModelViewSet` has a method [`create`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L19) that returns `Response` object. The response object is subtype of `Django Response`. Hence you can change behavior using [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L423) into the `create` method. For example:

```
class entry_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class= EntrySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(entry_ViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # here may be placed additional operations for
        # extracting id of the object and using reverse()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to='https://google.com')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.partial = True
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I never thought of overriding create but calling the super first. Very awesome- thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you know if this is documented somewhere apart from the code ?

Comment: `from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: i actually find this interesting. thanks alot