# Unable to Redirect to homepage after login in Django

Tags: html, django

hay i'm new to django framework, i got issue that i can not solved. It is when i tried to redirect the admin to admin custom homepage using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, i set it to  /profile, but instead go to homepage it raised "Page not found (404)"

here's my root url file

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('front_page.urls')),
path('accounts/login',views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
path('accounts/logout/', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
path('profile/', include('admin_page.urls')),
```

]

admin apps url

```html
app_name = "admin"

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.index, name='admin_index'),
    path('berita/', views.BeritaList.as_view(), name='all_berita'),
]
```

setting.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
```

homepage file

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, admin</h1>
  <p>Selamat di halaman utama administrator,silahkan menekan tombol dibawah untuk menginput Peta atau berita</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'admin:all_berita' %}" role="button">Berita</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="" role="button">Peta</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i got confused because it happen only when i try to redirect admin after login, can someone help me solve it, thank you

Comment: any error you've got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/home/'
```

change your login redirect url to the upper one, as there is no page called `/profile/`

you have

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.index, name='admin_index'),
    path('berita/', views.BeritaList.as_view(), name='all_berita'),
]
```

Comment: after i chenged to '/profile/home/' in settings.py, i got 'NoReverseMatch at profile/home/' error, should i add account to root url so it would be 'accounts/profile/' ?

Answer (score 0):

in your login view:

```
from djanog.shortcuts import redirect
....
....
....
def login():
    ....
    ....
    return redirect('home')
```

and notice that you should add `name=home` to your `urls.py` file in your app while defining `path('', views.home, name=home)`.

EDIT:
for class based views, hence your case, you should probably head over to the question with the following link:

[Redirect after POST django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894155/redirect-after-post-django-rest-framework)

Comment: He's using class based login view, you may require to edit it from `def login` to `class LoginVIew`