# Redirect viewset to another viewset on Django Rest Framework after parsing data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a viewset A, where I will receive a bunch of data via querystring. I want to parse this querystring on viewset A, and then redirect the request with the parsed querystring to viewset B. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried insatiating the viewset B inside of A and then calling the get method manually to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried HttpResponseRedirect, as suggested in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894155/redirect-after-post-django-rest-framework

Comment: @NickODell the URL for viewset B depends on where my DRF server is hosted, so I'd like it if the code didn't rely on that

Comment: You don't need to provide the full URL. You can provide just the part after the hostname. E.g. if `mysite.com/page` redirects to `/page2`, then the browser interprets that as `mysite.com/page2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect from an action in ViewsetA to an action in ViewsetB, here's how you can do it using the two different approaches mentioned before:

**HTTP Redirect Approach:**

Redirecting via HTTP will involve creating a URL for the action in ViewsetB and then sending an HTTP 302 response to redirect the client to that URL.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.urls import reverse
from urllib.parse import urlencode

class ViewsetA(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def action_in_a(self, request):
        # Do your parsing here
        parsed_data = parse_querystring(request.GET)
        
        # Prepare the new URL for the action in ViewsetB
        new_url = reverse('viewsetb-action_in_b') + '?' + urlencode(parsed_data)
        
        # Redirect to action in Viewset B
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND, headers={'Location': new_url})

class ViewsetB(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def action_in_b(self, request):
        # Handle your request as needed
        return Response(data={"message": "Handled in ViewsetB's action"})
```

**Internal Invocation Approach:**

This will involve manually invoking the action in ViewsetB from within ViewsetA.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ViewsetA(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def action_in_a(self, request):
        # Do your parsing here
        parsed_data = parse_querystring(request.GET)

        # Manually instantiate and invoke action in Viewset B
        viewset_b = ViewsetB()
        viewset_b.request = request
        viewset_b.format_kwarg = self.format_kwarg
        viewset_b.args = self.args
        viewset_b.kwargs = self.kwargs
        
        # Add parsed_data to the request or any other adjustments
        viewset_b.request.GET = parsed_data

        return viewset_b.action_in_b(request)

class ViewsetB(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def action_in_b(self, request):
        # Handle your request as needed
        return Response(data={"message": "Handled in ViewsetB's action"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Tried this but got the following error:

`NoReverseMatch at /api/available_strategy_allocation/
Reverse for 'fillsviewset-list' not found. 'fillsviewset-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`. Maybe it's because my Django project has multiple apps?

Comment: Just run `python manage.py show_urls` and choice the right one :)

Comment: The "Internal Invocation Approach" worked with a bit of tweaking! Thank you so much.